# sqlite3.OperationalError: table test has no column named

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlite, python-3.5

I am trying to take a dataframe and convert it into sql. I am creating the table first to set the unique indexing to allow for a rolling update with out having duplicates if there happens to be two A. Rods over time. Though I can't seem to shake this table column error and i don't know why.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 as sq

conn = sq.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def set_table():
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players(
              "#" INTEGER,
              " " REAL,
              "Named" TEXT,
              "B/T" TEXT,
              "Ht" TEXT,
              "Wt" TEXT,
              "DOB" TEXT);""")
    conn.commit()         

def set_index_table():
    c.execute(""" CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_unique
                  ON players (Named, DOB)""")
    conn.commit()

set_table()
set_index_table()

roster_active = pd.read_html('http://m.yankees.mlb.com/roster',index_col=0)
df = roster_active[0]
df = df.rename(columns={'Name': 'Named'})

df.to_sql('players', conn, if_exists='append')

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

sqlite3.OperationalError: table players has no column named

Thank you for your time.

Comment: "Name" TEXT, should be "Named"

Comment: Hey thanks for your time! I have edited the code so there is not a "name" issue anymore. Now i do get a similar error though which is: Table players has no column named. Still lost if you have any idea i would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am not completely sure why this doesn't work but I found how I could get it to work. I believe it had something to do with the dataframe index. So I defined what columns I wanted to select for the dataframe and that worked.

```
df = df[['Named','B/T', 'Ht','Wt','DOB']]
```